# Swift - How to get number values for selected rows in UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, selectedindex, multipleselection

I have a multiple selection on a `UITableview` made in Swift and I declare an Array that holds the `NSIndexPaths` of the selected `UITableView` Cells.

```
self.selectedRows = self.preferencesTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows()
```

How do I convert this array to readable terms. e.g self.selectedRows is NSlogged like :

Selected Items Strings [ {length = 2, path = 0 - 1},  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0},  {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}]

I wan to be able to convert this to : 1,2,3 .

In Objective C I enumerateObjectsWithOptions through the array and add the id of the array to a mutable array to get what I want.

```
[self.selectedRows enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse
usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = obj;
        [self.selectedCategorieItems addObject:[[[self.categoryArr
objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"id"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }];
```

How do I do this in Swift?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `map` function to return array of indices. It takes closure as argument and iterate over each element of array. `$0` is first argument, in our case this is selected index path:

```
let rows = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows()?.map{$0.row}
```

Please note that `rows` constant will be optional

Answer (score 2):

for swift 2.3

```
let rows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows.map{$0.map{$0.row}}
```